# How to obtain full html with all Shadow DOM elements expanded

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm stuck with this one. I'm creating a web crawler that should get the HTML of the page. The problem is when I'm reaching content rendered by JS. For that I need to use something like Selenium to obtain full HTML.

That's fine and works pretty well for pages created using for example Angular. The problem starts when we are reaching pages written in Polymer or any other framework with Shadow DOM and web components.
In that case I'm only getting the content till first shadow root.
The code that I use:

```
driver.execute_script("return document.body.innerHTML")
```

Yeah... So I would like to build a string with all custom elements inline.
all I get is:

```
<some-app page="homepage"></some-app><iron-a11y-announcer></iron-a11y-announcer>
```

You can imagine that it's not enough.
So I know that I can recursively access all shadow Root elements like.

```
document.querySelector("some-app").shadowRoot
```

I want to make it generic.
Any ideas? Any ready solutions?

Comment: Post the url of the website to inspect HTML code

Comment: well, I can't. It's internal site for company. But this: https://shop.polymer-project.org/ is the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one dirty solution I made:

```
def expand_element(element):
    subelements  = element.find_elements_by_xpath("./*")
    tag = element.get_attribute('tagName')
    tags_to_skip= ["TEMPLATE" , "svg" , "g" ,"path" , "STYLE" , "img" , "video" , ]
    if tag in tags_to_skip:
        return
    print(tag)
    self.counter+=1
    if self.counter %100 == 0: 
        print("==================="  ,  self.counter , "==================")
    
    shadowroot = expand_shadow_element(element)
    if shadowroot:
    
        subelements  = driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].querySelectorAll("*")', shadowroot)

    for obj in subelements:
        expand_element(obj)    

def expand_shadow_element(element):
    shadow_root = driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].shadowRoot', element)
    return shadow_root
```

Works only in chrome web driver  and I have to concatenate results, but it's the basic mechanism....